# Java - Scope of variables in JUnit test methods

Tags: java, testing, junit, scope

I have two classes A and B. One is a helper and other is for Integration Tests.
As shown below, Variables in TestInfo class are shared among the test methods in B.class.
I cannot use global declaration of TestInfo object in class B as I am running the tests in concurrent mode, where **each test runs in its own thread and they have their own testinfo object**.

As you can see, to **access or modify the variable from testinfo object in the test method, I need to call A.get() everytime** and declare a local variable to hold it. I have to do it in each method which looks redundant. Is there any better way where I can scope variable such that it's scope holds good for the methods inside it too?

```
class TestInfo {
int a;
int b;
int c;
}


class A() {
TestInfo testinfo;

TestInfo get() {
   return testinfo;
  }
}


class B() {

void test1() {
int a = A.get().getA();
int b = A.get().getB();
int c = A.get().getC();
A.get().setA("a");

}

void test2() {
int a = A.get().getA();
int b = A.get().getB();
int c = A.get().getC();
A.get().setA("test2");

}

void test3() {
int a = A.get().getA();
int b = A.get().getB();
int c = A.get().getC();
}

void test4() {
int a = A.get().getA();
int b = A.get().getB();
int c = A.get().getC();
A.get().setA("test4");
}

void helper_method1() {
int a = A.get().getA();
int b = A.get().getB();
int c = A.get().getC();
B.get().setB("helper");
}

void helper_method2() {
int a = A.get().getA();
int b = A.get().getB();
int c = A.get().getC();
}






}
```

Comment: _I cannot use global declaration of TestInfo object in class B as I am running the tests in concurrent mode, where each test runs in its own thread and they have their own testinfo object._.        
are you only reading `tesftInfo`  or updating them too inside your test methods?

Comment: You can call A.get() once in each method and use the result 3 times, for a trivial bit of simplification.  But I'd consider scrapping the getters entirely and making use of package-level access.

Comment: @Tintin I am updating them too